# Django rest framework: Log to text file a successful or failed requests

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am looking for a way to log to a text file, successful or failed api requests. This is to implement an audit trail kind of solution. Could anyone assist me or point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using class-based views you could simply override the function finalize_response. This function handles the request and the response so it would be possible to fetch even more information besides the failure or success of the request. For getting the status of the request you can use response.status_code to see if it was a successful call or a failure. Here a short example.

```
def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
    status = response.status_code
    # do something with it
    return super(YourViewName, self).finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Did it help you? Or are you still facing problems?

Comment: Hello @MisterNox i actually decided to implement logging from frontend using Redux. Thank you very much for your help sir

Comment: Okay, but thanks for your feedback. If it answered your initial question please mark it as accepted for other people in the future.